# Regular Expression: match hh:mm, hh.mm or h

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I'm looking for a regular expression to match different time formats (for a time tracking web-app) **in javascript**. The user can insert times with one of the following formats:

```
h
hh:mm
hh.mm
```

I can easily create a regular expression to match hh:mm and hh.mm, but i can't get the single hour format working.

This is my current regex:
`([0-2][0-9])(.|:)([0-5][0-9])`

Allowed character: `0-9`, `.` and `:`. 
If the user types any other character, the validation should fail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

following formats should work to:

h:mm (3:30)

solution: http://regexr.com?31gc3

Comment: What are you trying to capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `h` is in 24 or 12 hours format but for 24 hour this will do the job `/^([2][0-3]|[01]?[0-9])([.:][0-5][0-9])?$/` and for 12 hour - this `/^([1][0-2]|[0]?[0-9])([.:][0-5][0-9])?$/`

Comment: This will match `4.3`.  You'll want to avoid the `?` in `[0-5]?`.  Also, `[0-1]` could be reduced to `[01]`.

Comment: I've corrected it. Offcourse it will match even 4:14 which does not fit in the formats hh:mm or hh.mm, but I think that the system must be smarter (i.e. adding zeros in the beginning itself) rather than restricting the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a block optional by placing it in `( ... )?`  This is equivalent to `( ... ){0,1}` which allows zero or one references.

Your expression becomes:

```
/([0-2][0-9])((.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?/
```

This matches `12`, `12:30` and `12.30`.  It won't match `5`, `5:30`, or `5.30`. Enabling a single digit hour input can be done by making the first digit optional:

```
/([0-2]?[0-9])((.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?/
```

If you're using `.match`, you will notice you have 5 results:

```
["12:30", "12", ":30", ":", "30"]
```

You can reduce that to 3 by eliminating unnecessary matching when you turn `( ... )` into `(?: ... )`

```
/([0-2]?[0-9])(?:(?:.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?/
```

This gives you:

```
["12:30", "12", "30"]
```

**Update**

Based on your update, you want to match boundaries.  There are a couple ways to do this.

1. Starting with `^` will tie the front of your expression to the beginning of each line/string.
2. Ending with `$` will tie the end of your expression to the end of the string.
3. Starting or ending with `\b` will mandate that the edge is against a "boundary".

Putting that all together:

If you just want to match lines that contain nothing but the date you can use:

```
/^([0-2]?[0-9])(?:(?:.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?$/
```

This will not catch "hello  1.30" or "1.30  hello".

If you want to match lines that start with a date you could use:

```
/^([0-2]?[0-9])(?:(?:.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?/
```

But this will match "1.30000".

your best bet if you're looking for dates at the start of lines is:

```
/^([0-2]?[0-9])(?:(?:.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?\b/
```

As it will match "1.30 test" but not "1.300000".  Unfortunately, it will also match "1.30.30", but that is a limitation of JavaScript's RegExp processor.

If you're looking for times inside strings, this becomes:

```
/\b([0-2]?[0-9])(?:(?:.|:)([0-5][0-9]))?\b/
```

It matches "test 1.30 test" with the unfortunate case of matching stuff like ".10.10.10".

Comment: That's true.  Other answers have definitely taken this closer to the the logical conclusion with regards to accurate matching.  I'm more interested in the language features that make the matching possible.

Comment: That's not bad. No user try to log 27 hours and 30 minutes in the time tracking system... and if they try it, log files will alert :)

Problem with your Regex: a mixture of numbers and letters are correct too: http://regexr.com?31gc0

Comment: Updated.  This addresses the case where you are trying to find times that don't just make up the whole line, but are also in the start and middle of lines.  There are some limitations in JavaScript that will have false matches, but they should be limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to capture anything, just use this:

```
/[0-2]?\d[.:][0-5]\d/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?31g9u

---

If you want to capture the hours and the minutes, use this:

```
/([0-2]?\d)[.:]([0-5]\d)/
```

If your capturing has other requirements, please specify.

---

**Update:** I just realized that you might only want a single digit hour if no minutes are provided. If that's the case, use this:

```
/^(?:\d|[0-2]\d[.:][0-5]\d)$/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?31ga1

---

If you want to match something like `9:42`, but also match single digits, use this:

```
/^(?:\d|[0-2]?\d[.:][0-5]\d)$/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?31ga7

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `([0-2]\d)(\.|:)([0-5]\d)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `?` to make something optional. In your case, you want something like

```
([0-1]?[0-9])(\.|:)([0-5][0-9])
```

Adding the `?` allows it to accept something like 5:30.

Edit: also, the `.` stands for *any character*, so it needs to be escaped. You can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

the dot must be escaped if not between right brackets [0-9] is equivalent to \d

```
/(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3])([:.][0-5]\d)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

This one matches 12 hour time formats as well as just hours.

```
(([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[:.][0-5][0-9])|([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])

5      Pass
5.55   Pass
01.4   FAIL
01:59  Pass
1:45   Pass
```

If you want 24 hour, the part before the colon is `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])`